# Sidekiq: Find last job

Tags: mysql, ruby, sidekiq

I have two Sidekiq jobs. The first loads a feed of articles in JSON and splits it into multiple jobs. It also creates a log and stores a `start_time`.

```
class LoadFeed
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform url
    log = Log.create! start_time: Time.now, url: url
    articles = load_feed(url) # this one loads the feed
    articles.each do |article|
      ProcessArticle.perform_async(article, log.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The second job processes an article and updates the `end_time` field of the former created log **to find out, how long the whole process (loading the feed, splitting it into jobs, processing the articles) took.**

```
class ProcessArticle
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform data, log_id
    process(data)
    Log.find(log_id).update_attribute(:end_time, Time.now)
  end
end
```

But now I have some problems / questions:

> 1. `Log.find(log_id).update_attribute(:end_time, Time.now)` isn't atomic, and because of the async behaviour of the jobs, this could lead to incorrect `end_time` values. Is there a way to do an atomic update of a `datetime` field in MySQL with the current time?
> 2. The feed can get pretty long (~ 800k articles) and updating a value 800k times when you would just need the last one seems like a lot of unnecessary work. **Any ideas how to find out which one was the last job, and only update the `end_time` field in this job?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) you could do an update with one less query and let MySQL find the time:

```
Log.where(id: log_id).update_all('end_time = now()')
```

For 2) one way to solve this would be to update your end time only if all articles have been processed. For example by having a boolean that you could query. This does not reduce the number of queries but would certainly have better performance.

```
if feed.articles.needs_processing.none?
  Log.where(id: log_id).update_all('end_time = now()')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem Sidekiq Pro's [Batch](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) feature solves.  You create a set of jobs, it calls your code when they are all complete.

```
class LoadFeed
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def on_success(status, options)
    Log.find(options['log_id']).update_attribute(:end_time, Time.now)
  end

  def perform url
    log = Log.create! start_time: Time.now, url: url
    articles = load_feed(url) # this one loads the feed
    batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
    batch.on(:success, self.class, 'log_id' => log.id)
    batch.jobs do
      articles.each do |article|
        ProcessArticle.perform_async(article, log.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That would be a useful feature, but I can't afford Sidekiq Pro for an open source project ;)